# Layout algorithm performs differently on nodes with and without parents

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

Graph with added parents nodes: [image: Graph with added parents nodes]

Graph without added parents nodes: [image: Graph without added parents nodes]

The initial graph has only the data key from each object, ignore other keys, as they are added by cytoscape later.

This is the data from the graph with the added parent nodes:

```js
{
  nodes: [
    {
      data: {
        id: "eff571da-60dc-d2b2-599f-9289b0065c7e",
        entityName: "fb$PackagedProduct",
        name: "[pck] production-unit-test-attempt-1-case",
        props: {
          name: "[pck] production-unit-test-attempt-1-case",
          status: "Working",
          PackagedProduct: "[pck] production-unit-test-attempt-1-case"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 24, y: 24 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "e05e4efd-ea2b-1850-1f20-2871b916defe",
        entityName: "fb$FoodProduct",
        name: "production-unit-test-attempt-1",
        props: {
          name: "production-unit-test-attempt-1",
          businessId: "PMFG_PRD-F_51",
          revision: "1",
          status: "Approved",
          FoodProduct: "production-unit-test-attempt-1"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 98, y: 24 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "d926c1c3-8dac-f749-87ef-bb640cd6f4a5",
        entityName: "fb$PackagedProduct",
        name: "[even-bigger-pack] Ingredient 1",
        props: {
          name: "[even-bigger-pack] Ingredient 1",
          status: "Working",
          PackagedProduct: "[even-bigger-pack] Ingredient 1"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 172, y: 24 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "479a1c61-46da-32be-274a-155f80c00942",
        entityName: "fb$PackagedProduct",
        name: "[pck] Ingredient 1",
        props: {
          name: "[pck] Ingredient 1",
          status: "Working",
          PackagedProduct: "[pck] Ingredient 1"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 24, y: 98 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "9e435fbd-b502-efb3-ba9f-26ed64161e46",
        entityName: "fb$PackagedProduct",
        name: "[pck] Ingredient 2",
        props: {
          name: "[pck] Ingredient 2",
          status: "Working",
          PackagedProduct: "[pck] Ingredient 2"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 98, y: 98 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "709a9693-48c5-738f-ad30-0b972c3322de",
        entityName: "fb$PackagedProduct",
        name: "[pck] Ingredient 4",
        props: {
          name: "[pck] Ingredient 4",
          status: "Working",
          PackagedProduct: "[pck] Ingredient 4"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 172, y: 98 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "3bfa753b-a65f-528a-57dc-d28519510988",
        entityName: "fb$PackagedProduct",
        name: "[bigger-pck] Ingredient 1",
        props: {
          name: "[bigger-pck] Ingredient 1",
          status: "Working",
          PackagedProduct: "[bigger-pck] Ingredient 1"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 24, y: 172 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "e939086f-0530-8dae-3dd8-c98f26e343c7",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[even-bigger-pack] Ingredient 1",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234521",
          groupId: "d926c1c3-8dac-f749-87ef-bb640cd6f4a5"
        },
        parent: "d926c1c3-8dac-f749-87ef-bb640cd6f4a5"
      },
      position: { x: 172, y: 24 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "c05cd169-c8df-29da-09a3-90f30a53b484",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] Ingredient 4",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234538",
          groupId: "709a9693-48c5-738f-ad30-0b972c3322de"
        },
        parent: "709a9693-48c5-738f-ad30-0b972c3322de"
      },
      position: { x: 172, y: 98 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "1a834a7b-3d78-4ff4-6119-cd5b0c5ab86f",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[bigger-pck] Ingredient 1",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234514",
          groupId: "3bfa753b-a65f-528a-57dc-d28519510988"
        },
        parent: "3bfa753b-a65f-528a-57dc-d28519510988"
      },
      position: { x: 24, y: 172 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$ProductionUnit",
        level: 0,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          expiryDate: "30-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          identifier: "32b71cca-252a-4691-a9b3-f7a393be1ac6",
          groupName: "production-unit-test-attempt-1",
          productionDate: "10-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          groupId: "e05e4efd-ea2b-1850-1f20-2871b916defe",
          quantityV: "3000 kg",
          target: "123459625947323531"
        },
        parent: "e05e4efd-ea2b-1850-1f20-2871b916defe"
      },
      position: { x: 98, y: 24 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "f3a649b3-5643-78aa-c29a-1d7a85f70a93",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] Ingredient 1",
          when: "30-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234569",
          groupId: "479a1c61-46da-32be-274a-155f80c00942"
        },
        parent: "479a1c61-46da-32be-274a-155f80c00942"
      },
      position: { x: 24, y: 98 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "8155a819-e0b3-64fb-9d21-130974b1071e",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] Ingredient 2",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234583",
          groupId: "9e435fbd-b502-efb3-ba9f-26ed64161e46"
        },
        parent: "9e435fbd-b502-efb3-ba9f-26ed64161e46"
      },
      position: { x: 98, y: 98 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "9afd2217-41a6-ae23-69cc-5cda7244fe89",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: 1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] production-unit-test-attempt-1-case",
          when: "16-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "123459625947323531",
          groupId: "eff571da-60dc-d2b2-599f-9289b0065c7e"
        },
        parent: "eff571da-60dc-d2b2-599f-9289b0065c7e"
      },
      position: { x: 24, y: 24 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    }
  ],
  edges: [
    {
      data: {
        source: "f3a649b3-5643-78aa-c29a-1d7a85f70a93",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "2.5 %", source: "376104250021234569" },
        id: "0adf88a6-e78f-4057-a819-35245ca024f0"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "c05cd169-c8df-29da-09a3-90f30a53b484",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "7.5 %", source: "376104250021234538" },
        id: "a2945e05-4751-4043-98da-649a6a1bbde0"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "1a834a7b-3d78-4ff4-6119-cd5b0c5ab86f",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "66.67 %", source: "376104250021234514" },
        id: "ef1f880e-b774-4f6b-a14a-214d787f72b3"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "e939086f-0530-8dae-3dd8-c98f26e343c7",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "30.83 %", source: "376104250021234521" },
        id: "3c65eddb-bc76-42c0-90c0-b0d0afcb127f"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "8155a819-e0b3-64fb-9d21-130974b1071e",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "100 %", source: "376104250021234583" },
        id: "fa9153c8-a061-4c94-8e4d-02a99e2eff50"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        target: "9afd2217-41a6-ae23-69cc-5cda7244fe89",
        entityName: "custom_fb$ProductionUnit_fb$LogisticUnit",
        name: "No Name",
        props: {},
        id: "b28722aa-711b-4c60-b4f0-dc8f66373b22"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the graph data without the parents nodes:

```js
{
  nodes: [
    {
      data: {
        id: "e939086f-0530-8dae-3dd8-c98f26e343c7",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[even-bigger-pack] Ingredient 1",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234521",
          groupId: "d926c1c3-8dac-f749-87ef-bb640cd6f4a5"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 12, y: 532 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "c05cd169-c8df-29da-09a3-90f30a53b484",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] Ingredient 4",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234538",
          groupId: "709a9693-48c5-738f-ad30-0b972c3322de"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 12, y: 272 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "1a834a7b-3d78-4ff4-6119-cd5b0c5ab86f",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[bigger-pck] Ingredient 1",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234514",
          groupId: "3bfa753b-a65f-528a-57dc-d28519510988"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 12, y: 402 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$ProductionUnit",
        level: 0,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          expiryDate: "30-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          identifier: "32b71cca-252a-4691-a9b3-f7a393be1ac6",
          groupName: "production-unit-test-attempt-1",
          productionDate: "10-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          groupId: "e05e4efd-ea2b-1850-1f20-2871b916defe",
          quantityV: "3000 kg",
          target: "123459625947323531"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 342, y: 272 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "f3a649b3-5643-78aa-c29a-1d7a85f70a93",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] Ingredient 1",
          when: "30-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234569",
          groupId: "479a1c61-46da-32be-274a-155f80c00942"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 12, y: 142 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "8155a819-e0b3-64fb-9d21-130974b1071e",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: -1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] Ingredient 2",
          when: "11-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "376104250021234583",
          groupId: "9e435fbd-b502-efb3-ba9f-26ed64161e46"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 12, y: 12 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        id: "9afd2217-41a6-ae23-69cc-5cda7244fe89",
        entityName: "fb$LogisticUnit",
        level: 1,
        name: "No Name",
        props: {
          groupName: "[pck] production-unit-test-attempt-1-case",
          when: "16-9-2019 12:00:00 EEST",
          sscc: "123459625947323531",
          groupId: "eff571da-60dc-d2b2-599f-9289b0065c7e"
        }
      },
      position: { x: 672, y: 272 },
      group: "nodes",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: false,
      classes: ""
    }
  ],
  edges: [
    {
      data: {
        source: "f3a649b3-5643-78aa-c29a-1d7a85f70a93",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "2.5 %", source: "376104250021234569" },
        id: "23bbca52-ddb2-44c9-bb43-7f64a1153638"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "c05cd169-c8df-29da-09a3-90f30a53b484",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "7.5 %", source: "376104250021234538" },
        id: "aed1195d-ae72-42ad-a4ea-20792eba9c2f"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "1a834a7b-3d78-4ff4-6119-cd5b0c5ab86f",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "66.67 %", source: "376104250021234514" },
        id: "58ab4084-90b9-48a1-880a-23c18335cf43"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "e939086f-0530-8dae-3dd8-c98f26e343c7",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "30.83 %", source: "376104250021234521" },
        id: "f699a603-7d5c-4f0a-a289-8c9d227365e3"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "8155a819-e0b3-64fb-9d21-130974b1071e",
        target: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        entityName: "fb$Production_Source",
        name: "No Name",
        props: { quantityE: "100 %", source: "376104250021234583" },
        id: "506215ad-a4ac-4ffc-9af1-2571befc20b2"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    },
    {
      data: {
        source: "7614a68d-a03f-411b-ba5b-e3e6c6b6294c",
        target: "9afd2217-41a6-ae23-69cc-5cda7244fe89",
        entityName: "custom_fb$ProductionUnit_fb$LogisticUnit",
        name: "No Name",
        props: {},
        id: "922cdd9c-4dfe-42d6-9026-eaf58bcd7ba9"
      },
      position: { x: 0, y: 0 },
      group: "edges",
      removed: false,
      selected: false,
      selectable: true,
      locked: false,
      grabbable: true,
      pannable: true,
      classes: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

My layout options are the same throughout both renditions:

```js
const layoutOptions = {
  name: "elk",
  elk: {
    algorithm: "layered",
    nodeNode: 100,
    nodeNodeBetweenLayers: 300
  }
};
```

I use the [Cytoscape-Elk](https://github.com/jfstephe/cytoscape.js-elk) layout library. Can anyone point what I am doing wrong or what is the root cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Isn't this expected behaviour?

Comment: @maxkfranz, it is not that intuitive that this is the expected behaviour and why should it be? The only difference between the graphs is that every node has a parent. Why should the layout change? Why do you say that this is expected?

Comment: If you give a layout different input (e.g. a different subgraph), then the output may be different.  For details about Elk's behaviour, you should refer to the Elk documentation: https://github.com/OpenKieler/elkjs https://www.eclipse.org/elk/documentation.html